# Step Function confusion

Tags: riemann-integration, step-function

Suppose $g(x) = 1$ if $x=0$ and $g(x)=0$ otherwise, would that be a considered a step function? I assume it is because $g(x)$ can be written as the indicator function acting on $x=1$?
Sorry if this question sounds silly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because a step function is a function that can be written as finite linear combination of indicator functions.